# Is there any possibility to store variable from remote server output inside script?

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm little aware that, we can store command output as variable in local script as below:

```
variable=$(command)
```

Like this way, can we store remote command output as variable? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. For Ex:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh remote@hostname << EOF
variable=$(command1)
variable=$(command2)
variable=$(command3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Variable=`ssh remote@hostname "command1" </dev/null`
```

The stdout of a remotely executed command/script can be directly assigned to local variable easily.